# Why Index Only Scan is taking so long?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Why does executing my simple query

```
select count(this_.Id) as y0_ from Activity this_
```

take so long (more than 10 minutes this time)?

Here is the query plan (output of the EXPLAIN ANALYZE):

```
QUERY PLAN  
 Aggregate (cost=854047.36..854047.37 rows=1 width=4)
> (actual time=728525.277..728525.277 rows=1 loops=1)   
->  Index Only
> Scan using activity_pkey on activity this_  (cost=0.56..805401.87
> rows=19458196 width=4) (actual time=36.961..725381.557 rows=19517989
> loops=1)  
> Heap Fetches: 10351403  
Total runtime: 728533.529 ms
```

And PostgreSql version:

```
PostgreSQL 9.3.5 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2, 64-bit
```

The index is here too, on the Id field:

```
ALTER TABLE public.activity
ADD CONSTRAINT activity_pkey 
PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Answer (score 13):

Index Only Scan in PostgreSQL has to look sometimes into the table (heap), because index pages don't contain information about tuple visibility.
That's how many rows were fetched from the index:

> (actual ... rows=19517989

And that's how many rows were re-checked in the heap:

> Heap Fetches: 10351403

To speed it up, you should run vacuum on you table: `vacuum Activity`

Vacuum will update [visibility map](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/storage-vm.html), and after that Index Only Scan will be able to perform using (almost) only index pages.

Comment: I have done the VACUUM (VERBOSE, ANALYZE) on the Activity table. After this, the output of the same SELECT command looks like this: http://pastebin.com/KJqHTAGA Even now the amount of rows, which were re-checked is huge. But indeed, it executes three times faster.

Comment: Do you think there are any future improvements available?

Comment: I can't see one if you need exact count. But if an estimation if sufficient for you, read this: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting

Comment: It is used in paging (Grid component in Tapestry), so it supposed to be the exact value. Maybe I will narrow down the needed activities by quering only for those within last month.

Comment: Vacuuming the table didn't help. I had the exact same result. Also, tried vacuum full which never did finish (5'+) and I have to terminate it. Any ideas ?